# ModelBinding: POST data (possibly from Ruby) in MVC4/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, model-binding

We're integrating with chargify http://www.chargify.com and I need to handle webhooks from Chargify in our MVC4/C# server.
Chargify sends  POST data in the (ruby) way - sub objects are delimited in square brackets, like so:

```
POST /1ffaj2f1 HTTP/1.1
X-Chargify-Webhook-Signature: 526ccfd9677668674eaa6ba5d447e93a
X-Chargify-Webhook-Id: 11238622
User-Agent: Ruby
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 5159
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*; q=0.5, application/xml

id=11238622&event=payment_success&payload[subscription][activated_at]=2013-05-22%2001%3A25%3A20%20-0400&payload[subscription][balance_in_cents]=0&...
```

The issue is that on the .NET side, the default model binder does not like the square brackets`[` `]` and instead expects subobjects to be delimited in a dotted notation like `a.b.c.d=value`

What are my options to make the model binder work? I can think of the following:

1. Hook into the request with a delegating handler, read the req body and replace [] with dot (.). However, this feels dicey at the least
2. Write a custom model binder that will work with `[]` - hopefully being able to delegate to the default handler somehow. Dunno how to go about this - but would love to hear some thoughts.
3. Just use a `formcollection` param in the Action. Process the form collection keys to form a recursive dictionary based on the keys. This also means that I have to deal wiht strings throughout (for dates, ids etc etc)

What's the best way and how do I go about it.

Comment: U hv listed all the 3 possible approaches which came in mind after reading ur question. Upvoting ur question :-) Option 2 u mentioned is the best approach if u can achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think I've finally solved this one using `Request.Filter` property [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filter.aspx)

Also to note - There's no delegating handler in MVC - that's WebApi stuff (some of these things are made just to lead you astray!)

Basically, wrote a decorator over Stream that reads the input stream, replaces the square brackets with dots and then stores it in another stream. 
There's a check in Application_BeginRequest that sees if the input request is for the 'correct' controller and if so, creates a decorator instance and sets it to Request.Filter.

Code [here](https://gist.github.com/raghur/5868913). feel free to fork :)

**[Update - 2013.08.19]:** As noted by @benpage below in comments, we also need the original unmodified stream for SHA256 validation.
I ended up exposing the unmodified stream contents from the decorator and downcasting the `Request.InputStream` property in the controller to get the unmodified content for signature validation.

Comment: i like this answer - except it changes the input stream and you can no longer validate it against the sha256 hash sent with the request (unless you convert it back)

Comment: @benpage - good point on the SHA check. I'll need to probably go back and check.

Comment: FWIW - i used your code (thanks!) but did the SHA check in it as well - and either returned your modified documentcontents, or returned a string ("ERROR") - then i checked for that string in the inputstream in my authorise attribute. if it finds it, i'm just returning a httpnotfoundresult.

Comment: I've tried out your resolution as well as something similar to your 3rd option ... cycling through the form collection keys and properly formatting them ,and then calling TryUpdateModel (I've read a few places that this doesn't support nested objects though). Both implementations will bind the id and event_type property but neither of the nested objects of payload. Both site and subscription are null. I'm using Postman replicate the chargify webhook post so I know that there is indeed data in the site and subscription kvp's.  Did you run into this issue?