# ASP.NET MVC 4 ModelBinding using [] notation instead of dot

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, alamofire

I'm updating an old site to allow access from an iOS app. The iOS app using Alamofire and serializes parameters with a bracket notation, like `object[property]=value`. But ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder prefers dot notation like `object.property=value`.

Can I tell the model binder to user the bracket notation instead or even better to allow both dot and bracket notation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution written by someone facing the same problem:
https://gist.github.com/raghur/5868913

The guy wrote a decorator over Stream that reads the input stream, replaces the square brackets with dots and then stores it in another stream.

Here is the link to thread:
[ModelBinding: POST data (possibly from Ruby) in MVC4/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290035/modelbinding-post-data-possibly-from-ruby-in-mvc4-c)